# How to get webpack to reflect JavaScript changes along side lite-server

Tags: npm, webpack, lite-server

Through npm, is there anyway possible we can get webpack to reflect javascript changes on the fly, when lite-server is running?  I have to do a npm run build every single time I have JavaScript changes.

Lite-server is doing an excellent job in updating my css changes on the fly whenever I save my .scss files.  But in regards to webpack and the JavaScript files, its another story.

Thanks for any tips

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Webpack has a [watch mode](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/watch/#watch).
You can either call webpack with `--watch` or put `watch: true` in your webpack config. This will keep it running and recompile if something changes.

Also consider to look into [webpack-dev-server](https://github.com/webpack/webpack-dev-server)

Comment: I got it working.  Thanks! But can the webpack-dev-server be configured to also watch for scss changes? not just js changes? Is that tricky to setup?

Comment: You can compile scss with webpack as well. If you do that, webpack-dev-server will watch these changes too. https://github.com/webpack-contrib/sass-loader